# How to make the prediction interval to cover the area without datapoint

Tags: r

I am trying to plot a prediction interval for a linear model in ggplot.

Following the instructions in other websites, I have written the following
codes:

```
model1 <- lm(rate ~ conc, data=origin)
temp_var <- predict(model1, interval="prediction")
new_df <- cbind(origin, temp_var)

ggplot(data = new_df, aes(x = conc, y = rate))+
geom_line(data=plot, aes(x=x, y=y, group=group)) +
geom_point(color="#2980B9", size = 0.5) +
geom_line(aes(y=lwr), color = "#2980B9", linetype = "dashed")+
geom_line(aes(y=upr), color = "#2980B9", linetype = "dashed")
```

Since I want to predict the values outside my data range (blue points), I
would like to extend the prediction band. But the problem is the "lwr" and
"upr" generated by predict function only provides values within my data
range, as shown in the following graph.

[image: example plot]

Is there any way to extend the prediction band?

Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: I think you can achieve this with `expand.grid`.

Comment: Your example is not entirely reproducible, so this is to some extent guesswork. What I think you need is the `newdata` argumenting within `predict`, it tells predict on what data it should make the predictions. This code will give you predictions for the range from 0 to 1:     `temp_var <- predict(model1, newdata= data.frame(conc = seq(0, 1, 0.1), interval="prediction")`